# How to a list private Python packages as Conda requirement?

Tags: python, conda

I've got a need to create and ship `conda` envs that list packages that need to remain private.  It would be especially handy to list dependencies using an URL to a (company internal) GitLab instance.

Is there a way to register dependencies with `conda` using a repo URL? Is there also some other way to include Python packages you have a source distribution for, but cannot be hosted on a regular channel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know before hand what needs to remain private ship direct-reference eggs, or used zoned `index-urls`, and `extra-index-urls`, or in the conda-meta stuff like [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#source-from-git):

```
# requirements.txt
gevent
publicthing==1.2
someother==0.1

# private packages
file://package/egg/here
-e git+ssh://priv.gitlab.some.org/some/privpack.git#egg=privpack
--extra-index-url https://build.priv.gitlab.some.org/some/pypi/simple
```

I'd guess private here would mean sdist/dist build artifacts like tars, eggs, wheels, some URI/URL only accessible on a local network.

Like where the package is hosted should be indicator enough of labeling something as "private". Like the build artifacts are available, or they are not through some availability mechanism. (network location, building locally, shipped binaries, etc)

using pypi/pip.

- https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html#requirements-file-format

conda meta build info :

```
source:
  - url: https://build.priv.gitlab.some.org/some/pypi/simple/privpack/a.tar.bz2
    folder: stuff
  - url: https://build.priv.gitlab.some.org/some/pypi/simple/privpack/b.tar.bz2
    folder: stuff
```

- https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html

examples:

- https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes
- https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/blob/c2eb600f8545cd21aa9e50a8bb8a81df7fd3c915/r-packages/r-yaml/meta.yaml#L10
- https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/blob/a796713805ac8eceed191c0cb475b51f4d00718c/python/pyserial/meta.yaml#L5
- https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html#source-from-git
- https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html#source-from-a-local-path

related :

- https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/admin-guide/install/config/config-client#kerberos-configuration
- https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/admin-guide/install/config/kerberos-example
- https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/admin-guide/install/config/config-client#pip-configuration
- https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html#git